# Change Detection process and which exact time check OnPush properties

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

In https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

He say that angular has 14 operations but which exact moment it's checked if the component is ChecksEnabled == false (OnPush) and especially if it's OnPush at what time it checks some @Input properties has changed to run the process inside it? And continue with the check in the DOM and invoke the required life cycles ?

And if the value is a new reference, it will run the check only on the properties of that value of @Input or at all in the binding? Agree with me that it would be much more performatic if he just checks the value bindings of that element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At which exact moment it's checked if the component is ChecksEnabled
>   == false (OnPush)

It's happening when Angular runs checks for child views:

- runs change detection for a child view (repeats the steps in this list)

Here is the relevant code:

```
function callViewAction(view: ViewData, action: ViewAction) {
  const viewState = view.state;
  switch (action) {
    ...
    case ViewAction.CheckAndUpdate:
      if ((viewState & ViewState.Destroyed) === 0) {
        if ((viewState & ViewState.CatDetectChanges) === ViewState.CatDetectChanges) {
          checkAndUpdateView(view);
        } else if (viewState & ViewState.CheckProjectedViews) {
          execProjectedViewsAction(view, ViewAction.CheckAndUpdateProjectedViews);
        }
      }
      break;
```

> At what time it checks some @Input properties has changed to run the
>   process inside it

This is performed for this step:

- updates input properties on a child component/directive instance

To learn more about it read [The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce)

> And continue with the check in the DOM and invoke the required life
>   cycles ?

This will be done on:

- updates DOM interpolations and bindings for the current view if properties on current view component instance changed

To learn more read [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)

Comment: Hey Maximus, thank you for the reply! But in your post the operations are in order of execution? because the operation 'updates input properties on a child component/directive instance' there's nothing on OnPush and the operation 'runs change detection for a child view (repeats the steps in this list)' will be called after this process, the question is: the first code in your reply only skip if OnPush but where and the exact time the verification checks only is new input value updates de view? and why callViewAction is called after checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline?

Comment: hey, I'm sorry but I cannot give you precise callstack of everything Angular is doing. For that you will have to read sources yourself. Angular *always* checks bindings relevant for the child views regardless they are OnPush or not. And it does this before it runs checks for the child view. This is because if Input properties change the ViewState of the child component has to be updated to `ChecksEnabled` so that when time comes for checking the child component the check in the `callViewAction` passes

Comment: Thx! I do think I could express myself right, but a component OnPush is skipped from cd if Input properties were not changed ok! the question is, what the moment it's happening because the first code only the skip happen and nothing about check Input properties. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: as I said, it happens in the `updates input properties...`, here is the [relevant passage](f4b9) from the article. See `sets state to checksEnabled if a component uses OnPush strategy` step. I will probably rename `updates input properties on...` to `checks and updates input properties...`. I also just swapped operation 2 with operation 3. `ChecksEnabled` is set before the check for embedded views is performed

Comment: wow, great dude, thank you for the amazing explanation, the angular community will love your work.